# Magento 2 : What tables should be created to make product price Store-view wise? [ Multi Storeview Pricing ]

Tags: magento2, database, store-view, pricing

I want to create functionality like product prices can be set at the store-view level for that I've added one more option as Storeview in a configuration for

> **Stores > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Price**

It's already done the price is changing properly store-view wise in the backend also showing on frontend but **on a listing page, price filter in layered navigation is not showing products according to the price I've set store view wise.**

At first, I thought to create a custom field **store_id** in

> `catalog_product_index_price`

**since it's default Magento table, it's not a good idea to change the default tables so I want to create a separate table like**

> `catalog_product_index_price_store`

There are a number of tables in the database related to `catalog_product_index_price`.

```
catalog_product_index_price
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_replica
catalog_product_index_price_tmp
catalog_product_index_tier_price
catalog_product_index_website
```

> The problem is, I don't know which tables would be affected by this
>   and which are the exact tables, I have to create that affected tables as
>   well. Should I update all the tables related to price or are there any other tables than listed above?

**Some tables are creating during indexing, so how can I create tables during indexing?**

Answer (score 1):

We have the next tables list created for our solution:

```
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_bundle_selection_price
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_entity_tier_price
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_replica
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_price_tmp
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_store
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_index_tier_price
ecombricks_store__catalog_product_store
ecombricks_store__downloadable_link_price
```

There are 75 core classes involved that you need to tweak with plugins.